# Android loading playlists function

Tags: java, android, io

```
public static ArrayList<Playlist> getAllPlaylists( Context context ){
    ArrayList<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    //this will get me all playlist files available for my application
    for( String file : context.fileList() )
        if( file.endsWith(".playlist") )
            fileList.add(file);

    for( String file : fileList ){
        Playlist newPlaylist = loadPlaylist( context, file );

        if( !newPlaylist.isEmpty() ){
            playlists.add(newPlaylist);
        }
    }

    return playlists;
}

private static Playlist loadPlaylist( Context context, String file ){
    Playlist playlist = new Playlist();

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(file);
            byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[ inputStream.available() ];
            inputStream.read(inputBuffer);
            String content = new String(inputBuffer);
            //each line holds a path so we split the content
            String[] files = content.split("\n");

            playlist.setName( files[0] );               
            for( int i = 1; i < files.length; i++ ){
                //This will just load the Song (artist, title etc.)
                //if somehow the path leads to nowhere or it is just not a 
                //music file, getSong() will return null
                Song song = MediaManager.getSong( context, files[i] );

                if( song != null )
                    playlist.addSong( song );
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return playlist;
}
```

The structure I chose for my playlist files is pretty simple. The first line is the name of that playlist and the following lines will contain a filepath which I can use later on to load a file and play it / display its data.

Here is an example of what they might look like :

```
My first Playlist
/sdcard/.../.../whatever.mp3
/sdcard/.../.../noway.mp3
/sdcard/.../.../seriously.mp3
```

How can I improve the speed of this process? It takes about 1 second for 1 file...

Comment: Nitpicking: it is legal to have a newline in path. You may want to extract filenames in a more diligent way.

Comment: If you aren't already, make sure to use `AsyncTask` so that the operation can be performed in the background without making your application not responding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### About the slowness...

I don't see obvious bottlenecks here. When you say "It takes about 1 second for 1 file..." do you mean:

- A single song? In this case the `MediaManager.getSong` is a prime suspect. Add logging before and after to measure the difference.
- An entire playlist file?

  - Are there many songs in a list?
  - Does it make a difference if all the files in the list are valid or invalid? Test with 100 valid files and 100 invalid files. If invalid files somehow cause `MediaManager.getSong` to be slow, you can try to add a check if the file exists before passing it to `MediaManager`.

These are mostly shots in the dark.

There are some other problems with your code that won't make your program faster but you should fix anyway.

#### Reading from streams

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available()) says this about `inputStream.available()`:

> Returns an estimated number of bytes that can be read or skipped
>   without blocking for more input.
>
> Note that this method provides such a weak guarantee that it is not
>   very useful in practice.

Don't use it this way. Read like this instead:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(file);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    files.add(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();

Iterator<String> iter = files.iterator();
playlist.setName(iter.next());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String path = iter.next();
    Song song = MediaManager.getSong(context, path);
    if (song != null) {
        playlist.addSong(song);
    }
}
```

An important mistake you did there that you didn't close the input stream. Remember to close resources that you opened.

#### Use interface types instead of implementations

Instead of this:

> ```
> ArrayList<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();
> ```

Use the interface type in declarations, like this:

```
List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();
```

#### Style issues

This code doesn't follow the standard spacing rules, and the convention of using braces even for one-line statements:

> ```
> for( String file : context.fileList() )
>     if( file.endsWith(".playlist") )
>         fileList.add(file);
> ```

This is the recommended style:

```
for (String file : context.fileList()) {
    if (file.endsWith(".playlist")) {
        fileList.add(file);
    }
}
```